# Image artifacts with memcpy

Tags: c++, framebuffer

I'm adding custom resolution to very old game(7 kingdoms) and i have issue, with artifacted output. This game using SDL framework

[image]

Code responsible for this:

```
void IMGcall IMGcopy(char* imageBuf, int imgPitch, char* backBuf, int backPitch, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{

    std::cout << imageBuf << "\n" << imgPitch << "\n" << backBuf << "\n" << backPitch << "\n" << x1 << "\n" << y1 << "\n" << x2 << "\n" << y2 << "\n";
    int width = x2 - x1 + 1;
    int height = y2 - y1 + 1;
    int dest = y1*imgPitch + x1;
    int src = y1*backPitch + x1;
    for (int j=0; j<height; ++j, dest+=imgPitch, src+=backPitch)
    {
        memcpy( &imageBuf[ dest ], &backBuf[ src ], width );
    }
}
```

args values are:

```
???
1440
//here goes binary backBuf
1440
0
0
1439
899
```

What am i missing?

P.S. Sorry for might be noobish question, but i'm primary coding in scripted languages(ruby, python), but want to add feature to old game, since im playing it with my friends

Comment: Have you tried checking for buffer overruns, e.g. on `imageBuf` or `backBuf`? Valgrind is your friend ...

Comment: @BenjaminBannier this can be an issue, since on screenshow, it doesnt cover whole size, but just quarter, ill check

Comment: how are you outputting `imageBuf` and `backBuf` as a string on the first line and then `memcpy`ing binary data into it later?

Comment: Assuming `imageBuf` is actually a binary buffer that's supposed to hold the screen image, you don't seem to be clearing it before you start?

Comment: @MattMcNabb do i need to do this, since that screen is actually first what will be displayed?

Comment: I dont' know exactly what you are doing, but your screenshot shows a buffer with some garbage in the background and your question seems to be "how do I get rid of that garbage"

Comment: @MattMcNabb, yes, you're right. I will try to clear buffer before application start. Can i do something like `bacBuff = nil`; to clear it, or its more complex operation?

Comment: @Avdept well your `memcpy` is reading from `backBuf` and writing to `imageBuf` so I figured that `imageBuf` was the whole screen. If not then  I don't know what you're doing. It might help if you provided some more context and some more code to what you're doing.